# Truffle + INFURA remote provider deployment. Migrations not running

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-deployment, infura, web3-providers

I am running into the same issue proposed by [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16274/truffle-hanging-on-deploying-migrations). I cannot resolve it because I am using a remote provider (INFURA), per [this document](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider).

My code looks like this:

```
var ethwallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');
var ProviderEngine = require("web3-provider-engine");
var WalletSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/wallet.js');
var Web3Subprovider = require("web3-provider-engine/subproviders/web3.js");
var Web3 = require("web3");

// Import the raw private key of the admin
const keys = require('../test/keystores/keys.json');
const admin_key = keys.admin.privateKey;
const admin_addr = keys.admin.address;

// Add the admin key to the provider. This will unlock the account so it can
// deploy the contracts and run the tests.
var wallet = ethwallet.fromPrivateKey(Buffer.from(admin_key, 'hex'));
var engine = new ProviderEngine();

// Start the infuranet provider
var infuranet = "https://infuranet.infura.io";
var engine = new ProviderEngine();
engine.addProvider(new WalletSubprovider(wallet, {}));
engine.addProvider(new Web3Subprovider(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider(infuranet)));
engine.start();

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    infura: {
      network_id: 5810,
      provider: engine,
      from: admin_addr
    },
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*"
    }
  }
};
```

And I am running:

```
truffle migrate --network infura
```

Which hangs indefinitely. This also happens if I run:

```
truffle compile --network infura
```

Or any other truffle action.

Is it possible to run this without a local node? I would like to deploy these to this network using the remote INFURA provider.

Comment: Instead of using `infuranet.infura.io` try with the url obtained when you registered to infura service.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem should be adding two more lines, which you can find in the last answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11685/truffle-infura-for-deployment).